# Please tell me how to make more than one building in farm and grow?

Tags: farm-and-grow

I have one building but how do you get more?

Answer (score 1):

There are three buildings:

- Pasture: 20 wood, level 2 infrastructure research
- Mill: 30 wood, level 3 infrastructure research
- Well: 50 wood, level 5 infrastructure research

The target field must be empty. All conditions must be met, or the option to build will not appear.

You might also consider a graveyard to be a building, but they build themselves, without requiring any help from you :)

Reference: [source code](https://github.com/stomf/Farm-Grow/blob/master/Field.as)